# Less compiler issue (probably)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, less

I have installed the less compiler extension
https://github.com/madskristensen/LessCompiler

When I create a less file and save it, it isn't building CSS and min.css file for me.

In the lower right corner, I clicked on the watermark and less is enabled for the project. What am I missing here?

Please take a look at the screenshot.

[image]

**Update 1:** 
I have created a test MVC site and added a less file to it. No CSS getting generated over here as well.

**Update 2:** 
I have installed web essential 2017 and WebCompiler is there now. Still no css files. Selecting the file and Shift+Alt+Q not working. Also when i right click on the file, i don't get re-compile menu option as being discussed in the following thread: 
https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/299

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 version 15.5.6

Comment: I have the same problem and I am using Visual Studio Community 2017. Even I tested with Community Preview 2017. @learning..., Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I stopped looking into it since the site i was working on was for a very specific use. I didn't use it at the end. I opened the case on the github product page and found no help from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. For me it turned out node was no longer in my path which is required to compile. The output tab has a drop down with LESS compiler as an option to help troubleshoot.